# How to turn off live tile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, pin-to-start, live-tiles

On Windows 10 I can right-click any tile in my Start menu and choose to turn off the live tile functionality, turning it into a static app icon.

Is there a way to do this in Windows 10 Mobile? If I tap-and-hold on a tile, the only options are to resize and unpin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you turn off "Background Apps" this will disable the live tiles. You can do this by going to "All Settings" and searching for "Background Apps". From there you can toggle the apps that you don't want the live tiles for.

This isn't a centralized method, but it will do the trick.

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately most of the apps whose live tiles I'm interested in disabling don't show up in the list of background apps.

Comment: If they are not in the background apps list and their is no option within the app itself then I am afraid you are out of luck. What is your motivation anyways? I like being able to see information at a glance.

Comment: Not all apps display useful information on the live tile. In my case, I have some photo editors that simply rotate photos, whereas I'd like to see just a static icon, for quick identification of which app is which.

Comment: Fair enough. I was just wondering.

Comment: Lacking an actual per-tile option like on PCs, this appears to be the next best thing, even if it doesn't work with all apps, so I'm marking your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to turn off a live tile in Windows 10 Mobile is through the app itself. Usually the app has this feature in its options.

Comment: You could post an example too.

Comment: In my experience not many apps have this setting.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft's instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/8622cb5c-9833-43ac-951d-fc9488fe1076/turn-live-tiles-off) worked for me. They said that,

> To turn a Live Tile off, make the tile small. Press and hold the tile,
>   then press the Resize button on the bottom-right corner of the tile.
>   When you’re done, press the Start button.

Article ID: 8622cb5c-9833-43ac-951d-fc9488fe1076

Comment: Doesn't work for me, making tiles small doesn't disable live tile functionality.

Comment: It's tricky.  I had to go through the process a few times before it "caught" with Outlook Mail.  I was sure I had applied it successfully to Groove Music, too, but it has reverted to a flippin' live tile.

Comment: Micr4osoft's instructions are not totally clear and open to interpretation.  I honestly don't recall which interpretation worked for me with Mail.  I think it was something like this:  1) Make the tile small.  2) Press and hold the small tile.  3) Press the Resize button (presumably while holding the tile).  4) Release the Resize button and the tile.  5) Press Start.  Good luck.  I'm still fighting with the Groove Music tile.  I'll pay careful attention and report any success.